# Adding styles to Header component for particular Route

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

This is my main app component in Reactjs:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <div className="minht">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={Product} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/order/:id" component={Order} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/address" component={AddAddress} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/orderhistory" component={MyOrders} />
        </div>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i want to add some special styles to my `Header` component only when i am in `/orderhistory` route.

my header component where i want to append a new className or styles:

```
return (
    <div className="navsize">
      <Navbar dark expand="md" className="bg-dark ">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-6 text-center text-lg-left ">
          <NavbarBrand className="mr-3">
            <Link className="text-decoration-none" to="/">
              <h1 className="text-white">SHOPPING</h1>
            </Link>
          </NavbarBrand>
        </div>
        <div className=" col-12 col-md-6">
          <ul className="d-flex  justify-content-center justify-content-lg-end pl-0">
            {users.userAuth ? userLinks : authLinks}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `Header` component implementation? It's nearly impossible to help fix code if we can't see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) React hook:

> The `useRouteMatch` hook attempts to `match` the current URL in the same
> way that a  would. It’s mostly useful for **getting access to the
> match data without actually rendering a `<Route>`**.

It returns `null` for non-matches, otherwise returns a [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object.

```
import { useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom;

...

const orderHistoryMatch = useRouteMatch("/orderhistory");

const orderHistoryClass = orderHistoryMatch ? "orderHistory" : "";
```

Append the computed classname to the element you want to conditionally style.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `useLocation` hook in Header to detect current location and base on that choose apropriate styles.

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Hooks/uselocation